# "We encountered an internal error. Please try again." AWS S3-SQS integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs

I keep getting this error, when I try to configure the S3 bucket to write the response to SQS.

Is there any way I can solve this?

> [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

S3/SQS integration does not currently support the use of FIFO queues, and your queue is a FIFO queue.

> The following features of AWS services aren't currently compatible with FIFO queues:
>
> - Amazon CloudWatch Events
> - Amazon S3 Event Notifications
> - Amazon SNS Topic Subscriptions
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/faqs/#fifo-queues

Answer (score 0):

Did you attach a policy like this to your SQS queue?

```
{
 "Version": "2008-10-17",
 "Id": "example-ID",
 "Statement": [
  {
   "Sid": "AllowS3ToPublishMessages",
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Principal": {
     "AWS": "*"  
   },
   "Action": [
    "SQS:SendMessage"
   ],
   "Resource": "sqs-episource-arn",
   "Condition": {
      "ArnLike": {          
      "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:s3:*:*:your-bucket-name"    
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

(replacing `sqs-episource-arn` with the full ARN for `EpisourceExp.fifo` and `your-bucket-name` with the bucket name of your S3 bucket)

Comment: Yeah. I did add it. It still throws that error

`{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Id": "example-ID",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "example-statement-ID",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "SQS:SendMessage",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-west-2:080983167913:EpisourceExp.fifo",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
          "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:s3:*:*:episourceexperiment2"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}`